# Prove that a group of order $56$ is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Prove that a group of order $56$ is not simple.

For this question my strategy was to look at the prime factorization of the order $$56 = 2^3 \cdot 7$$Notice then that $ 2 \nmid 7$ so we could use the $1\text{st}$ Sylow Theorem to determine there exists a subgroup of order $8 = 2^3$, call this subgroup $H$. This is necessarily a $2$-subgroup since $2 \mid 8$. Furthermore, this is a Sylow $2$-subgroup since $\lvert H \rvert = 8 = 2^3$ is the maximal power that divides $\lvert G \rvert = 56 = 2^3 \cdot 7$. Perfect, we can now apply the $3\text{rd}$ Sylow Theorem and we notice then that $$n_2(G) \mid \frac{\lvert G \rvert}{2^3} = \frac{2^3 \cdot 7}{2^3} = 7,\ \text{hence},\ n_2(G) \mid 7$$ Also that $$n_2(G) \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$$ Great, then since $7$ is prime then $n_2(G)$ can either be $1$ or $7$. But we notice that $$7 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$$ Which means I am unable to conclude that $H$ is normal by the proposition that states that any Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal if and only if $n_p(G) = 1$. I tried this tactic again with $7$ but found that the subgroup of order $7$, call it $K$, fell into the same trap. Where, $n_7(G)$ can be either $1,2,4, \text{or}\ 8$ but we notice that $$8 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$ Hence I am unable to conclude that $K$ is normal in $G$.

---

I emailed my professor asking for a tip on how to proceed here and he suggested that "It's correct to want to show that G contains either a normal sylow $7$-subgroup or a normal sylow $2$-subgroup. Do this by assuming otherwise and counting elements. Be careful with the intersection when doing your count, though."

I need a little help parsing this tip. By "assume otherwise" I suppose he means 'assume that $G$ does *not* contain a normal sylow $2$ or $7$-subgroup'?

Additionally, I'm not sure exactly what is meant by counting elements and how that can prove normality of $H$ or $K$. Initially I thought we could use Lagranges Theorem to calculate $$[G : H] = \frac{\lvert G \rvert}{\lvert H \rvert}$$ And show that $[G : H] = 2$ then use the fact that any subgroup with index $2$ is normal to prove normality but that clearly doesn't work, neither does it work for $K$. So, any guidance in how to proceed is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the question in the body of the message, not merely on the subject line. The subject line is not part of the content, any more than stuff you write on the outside envelope is part of the letter inside. You don't start a letter on the envelope, you don't start a post on the subject line.

Comment: The statement as written in the subject line is absurdly silly: you can prove that a group of order $56$ has a normal subgroup by noting that the trivial and whole groups are both normal subgroups. You actually want to prove it has a **proper**, **nontrivial** subgroup, or better, "prove that a group of order $56$ is not simple."

Comment: (Also, "the group of order $56$" is inaccurate, since there are many non-isomorphic groups of order $56$)

Comment: Thanks @ArturoMagidin for the tips. I strive to be able to write clearer and more deliberately but like most am a work in progress (probably more than most on this site tbh). I will take your criticisms into account and take more time when writing my subject to make sure it is accurate and conveys the intention of the problem, without room for misinterpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good idea, but you were looking at the wrong Sylow.

Consider the Sylow $7$-subgroups. By Sylow's Third Theorem, there is either $1$ or $8$ of them. If there is one, then it is normal and you are done.

If there are $8$ of them, then note that any two must intersect trivially; this accounts for $8\times 6 = 48$ nontrivial elements. This leaves only $8$ elements that are not of order $7$; that means that there can only be one Sylow $2$-subgroup (there aren't enough elements left for there to be more), and so the Sylow $2$-subgroup is normal.

Comment: Oh, wow that is slick indeed. I'm guessing the tip of to be careful with the intersections was referencing that distinction between counting the nontrivial elements vs just saying oh well we would have $8$ groups of order $7$ which means $56$ elements, not realizing each subgroup must contain the identity. Very interesting, thank you for the response.